# Local Symfony cant connect to mysql Service that runs inside Docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker, symfony

I have a local Symfony Project where I want to execute a Repository Function inside the code. The Problem is that I get an "Access Denied" Error. The credentials are correct because I can log into the adminer that also runs inside Docker.

System: MacOS
Docker-V: 4.24.2
Symfony-V: 6.4.3

Error-Message:

> An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:10.8.3
        platform: linux/arm64/v8
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_USER: root
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
    adminer:
        image: adminer
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
```

Database URL in the .env:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony6-test?serverVersion=10.8.3-MariaDB&charset=utf8mb4"
```

- I tried replacing 127.0.0.1 with localhost
- I looked at the Docker Container config with `docker inspect`. With the docker inspect it shows a different IP Address: `172.19.0.3`, but when I tried to use this address it gives me a "Network unreachable" Error
- I reset docker to factory mode, but this didn't fix the problem

Comment: i guess it comes from the port, MariaDB runs on port 3307  and I suggest you delete the native authenticator password

Comment: With your solution i get an SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away Error

Comment: you have replaced the port in your compose and .env?

Comment: Yes i changed the port

Answer (score -1):

Hello try this configs this is what I use for symfony:

```
database:
        image: mariadb:10.6
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dbpassword
            - MYSQL_USER=myuser
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=maypassword
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
        volumes:
            - ./var/database:/var/lib/mysql:delegated
```

also it would be useful if you post your php image configuration from docker-compose file.
If you want to connect to the db configure the port to 3307.

```
$ mysql -u myuser -P 3307 mydb -p
```

normally it should work on localhost if it didnt work try :

```
$ mysql -u myuser -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 mydb -p
```

of course change the variable names of user, pass and database name as you see fit.

Comment: Hi. I Will try your config. But i dont have a php image inside my docker container. The symfony runs local, not inside docker

Comment: I tried your config now and also tried to connect via the shell but this didnt work. I am still getting the Access Denied Error

Comment: mysql -u myuser -h localhost -P 3307 mydb -p
can you try this

Comment: I did. That was what i meant with my comment before

Comment: when you enter this command in the terminal, are you getting a password prompt ? 
mysql -u myuser -P 3307 mydb -p 
i just tried it locally and it is working fine.
Also try docker ps and please post it here